# jQuery Simple Quiz not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just learning Javascript and jQuery. I have made a simple quiz that is essentially broken, but I have narrowed the problem down to my code. I am certain that all the ids are linked, and that jQuery is connected correctly to the CDN. I know I could ask the questions one after another, but imo that is sloppy coding.

From http://pastebin.com/54JQwhAg

```
HTML: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="Utf-8">
        <title>The quiz to end all quizes</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/logo.png">
                <h2>This page is an experiment to see if I can use JavaScript and jQuery to make a quiz game.</h2>
                <p>Please answer with no punctuation.</p>
                <p id="show">Click here to show answers.</p>
                <img id="start" src="images/clickme.png">
            </div>
            <div id="answers">
                <!-- CHEATER!!! -->
                <p><span id="ans1"></span>Q: Who was the first African-American major league baseball player? A: Jackie Robinson</p>
                <p><span id="ans2"></span>Q: Who was the second U.S. President? A: John Adams</p>
                <p><span id="ans3"></span>Q: Where did the general keep his armies? A: In his sleevies</p>
                <p><span id="ans4"></span>Q: Why did the chicken cross the road? A: To get to the other side</p>
                <p><span id="ans5"></span>Q: Why did the scarecrow get a promotion? A: He was outstanding in his field</p>
                <h2 id="numright"></h2>
                <p id="hide">Click here to hide answers.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Javascript:
$(document).ready(function() {
    var score;
    var questions = [
                    "Who was the first African-American major league baseball player?", 
                    "Who was the second U.S. President?",
                    "Where did the general keep his armies?",
                    "Why did the chicken cross the road?",
                    "Why did the scarecrow get a promotion?"
                    ];
    var answers = [
                    "jackie robinson",
                    "john adams",
                    "in his sleevies",
                    "to get to the other side",
                    "He was outstanding in his field"
                    ];
    $('#answers').hide() // hide answers
    $('#start').click(function() {
        for (num=0; num<5, num++){
            var ans = prompt(questions[num], "Enter Answer Here")
            if (ans == answers[num])
                score++
            } // end if
        } // end for
        $('#answers').show() // show answers
        $('#show').hide() // hide show
        $('#numright').write('You got ' + score + '/5')
    }); // end click
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $('#answers').show() // show answers
        $('#show').hide() // hide show button
    }); // end click
    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $('#answers').hide() // hide answers
        $('#show').show() // show show button
    }); // end click    
}); // end ready
```

Basically, the parts that should be hidden dont load on start, and when the image that start the quiz is clicked, nothing happens. When I have tried to narrow down the problem to a line of code, parts of code randomly work and then not work, with no apparent correlation.

Comment: To add code, click the `{}` button in the toolbar and paste in your code. I have fixed it above.

Comment: Out of interest, since the errors were related to missing characters, what text editor are you using? One with code hints would probably be beneficial to avoid such future errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 errors going through the code, both within the for loop

Firstly your for loop had a comma instead of a semi colon after `num<5`

Secondly you were missing your opening curly brace on the if statement

Corrected:

```
for (num=0; num<5; num++) {
    var ans = prompt(questions[num], "Enter Answer Here")
    if (ans == answers[num]) {
        score++
    } // end if
} // end for
```

Also, there are a couple more things to note

Before you try to increment the variable `score` you need to initialise it;

```
var score = 0;
```

And further down, when outputting the score in the `<h2>` tag you use `.write()` as a function, I assume based on JavaScript's `document.write()`. In jQuery use `.text()` instead and the score outputs successfully.

[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDHnN/2/)